# “No such file or directory found” when building a project in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I’m new to C++, only experienced in Java so far, so please be precise with the answers.
I translate the error from German to English, so they might not match the English counterpart.

I was trying to set up the IDE Codeblocks on Ubuntu, and tried to test it with a simple Hello World program.
Trying to "Build and run" the program caused two errors in the build log:

```
"-------------- Build: Debug in TestProject (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -g  -c /home/marcel/Dokumente/Dokumente/Privat/Udemy/C++/Übung/TestProject/src/Main.cpp -o obj/Debug/src/Main.o
g++  -o bin/Debug/TestProject obj/Debug/src/Main.o   
g++: error: obj/Debug/src/Main.o: File or directory not found
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))"
```

I tried to look it up, but most people seemed to have more problems than just these two files. None of their Solutions worked.
So far I've wasted a few days trying to fix it, so I thought I would ask here.

Comment: For the future projects I strongly recommend to use English environment.

Comment: Does the file exist? I suggest to not use `Ü` or other "Umlaute" in file or directory names.

Comment: Do you have any weird #include ? because that might be produced with wrong linking, thus, the  compiler doesn't generate the .o and the linker cannot make the exe. Make sure the compiler generate that .o file

Comment: It has actually been about the 'Ü' at the start of my directory name, this has only costed me 3 days, and a lot of nerves; I'm an Idiot -_- I only needed to replace it with 'UE' and it worked fine :)

Comment: @mch I suggest not using software that fails with valid file names. *Do* use umlauts in filenames, it’s fine (and has been for decades).

Comment: Generally seems a lot of the Linux build tools really don't like spaces (generally by not double quoting/escaping when making another common line) and in some cases any non-ASCII character. So best to stick to simple directory and filenames.

Comment: @FireLancer Citation sorely needed. Virtually all tools (and certainly all *good* tools) deal just fine with spaces and special characters in filenames. The only notable exception is GNU make (but even that is generally fine with spaces in the parent folder). Anyway, this is almost certainly unrelated to the error. The command line is simply wrongly specified.

Comment: GNU make is normally my wall, because basically any Linux development will have a makefile somewhere sooner or later. True about the parent directory, but that still means no spaces within the project. People also often write other things that don't escape/quote things when passing command lines. Not got a solid list, but various things when ported to Window's not dealing with "C:\Program Files\" comes to mind.

Comment: @FireLancer “no spaces within the project” is an entirely reasonable limitation though: most, if not all, folders and files will mirror valid identifiers anyway. So GNU make works. As for tools not dealing with “C:\Program Files” etc, I’ve only one thing to say: don’t use them, they’re shit. At most, submit an issue/patch.